# Database and android connection and storing database on mobile

Tags: android, excel

I want to design android application in which whatever changes made by me through android application should reflect in database.Database should be stored on mobile.Whenever I want I can upload that data on server.So can some please help me in deciding what i should select to store data on mobile.Excel sheet or word File.Is it possible.

Comment: And if excel then how can i connect excel and android

Answer (score 0):

For the database stored on your device, use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

For the database on your server use, any popular RDBMS(`mysql`, `SQL server`, `oracle` ...)

Excel and word are `microsoft` business application  it will not help.

Read up on
[android.database.sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)